# Plain text paste on Firefox on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, firefox

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> does plain text paste on Chrome and Firefox on Linux and Windows (removes all HTML formatting from WYSIWYG pasted text).

I think Chrome honours <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, but this doesn't seem to work in Firefox 6.

Is there a shortcut to paste as plain text on Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Firefox doesn't support this, you can use [Plain Clip](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/plain-clip/) as a workaround.

Comment: Looks like I am out of luck :(